# C# class and Graphics

Tags: c#, forms, graphics

Continuation of thread: [C# Invalidate troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521507/c-sharp-invalidate-troubles). I created the class but now I get an Error 2   Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement. And I am trying to create the "Car" by Car aCar = new Car(50,100); that is where I am getting the error.
Thanks for the suggestions.

```
  class Car
    {
     private Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2F);
     private Pen pen2 = new Pen(Color.Green, 2F);
     int cost = 0; 
      int x, y;
      Graphics g;

public Car(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void printCar()
{

    g.DrawEllipse(pen1, x, y, 30, 30);
    g.DrawEllipse(pen1, x + 100, y, 30, 30);
    g.DrawRectangle(pen2, x - 5, y + 50, 140, 50);
    g.DrawLine(pen2, x + 15, y + 50, x + 30, y + 90);
    g.DrawLine(pen2, x + 30, y + 90, x + 90, y + 90);
    g.DrawLine(pen2, x + 90, y + 90, x + 110, y + 50);
    // Create string to draw.
    String drawString = "Price: " + (cost).ToString("C");
    // Create font and brush.
    Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
    SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    // Create point for upper-left corner of drawing.
    PointF drawPoint = new PointF(50, 95);
    // Draw string to screen.
    g.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint);


}
```

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    private Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2F);
    private Pen pen2 = new Pen(Color.Green, 2F);

    private double cost ;
    private int days = 0;
    private double air;
    private double automatic;
    int count;
    int m = 50;
    Car aCar = new Car(50, 60);

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        days = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Van")
        {
            cost = 110;
            label1.Text = "The Cost of van per day" + (cost).ToString("C");
            textBox1.Text = "1";
            textBox1.Focus();
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Car")
        {

            cost = 85.20;
            label1.Text = "The Cost of car per day" + (cost).ToString("C");
            textBox1.Text = "1";
            textBox1.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            cost = 135;
            label1.Text = "Van" + (cost).ToString("C");
            textBox1.Text = "1";
            textBox1.Focus();
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
        button1.Text = "Move";
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        if(count == 2)
            button1.Text = "Reset";
        if (count == 3)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "0";
            count = 0;
            comboBox1.Text = "select type of vehical";
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
            checkBox2.Checked = false;

        }
    }
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
       e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);

       if (count == 1)

       aCar.printCar();

      if (count == 2)
```

}

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: You say the error is happening on `Car aCar = new Car(50, 100)` except that line does not exist in your sample.  Please show us that section of your code.

Comment: FYI, this is not a discussion forum. You are asking a new question related to another question. You are not continuing a thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the Graphic object you are getting from the Paint event:

```
Public void printCar(Graphic g)
{
  // etc, etc
}
```

So that when you call it:

```
aCar.printCar(e.Graphics);
```

Answer (score 1):

The end of your `picturebox1_Paint` method opens an `if` statement but doesn't actually contain a body.  That is illegal:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);

   if (count == 1)

   aCar.printCar();

   if (count == 2)  // <-- This is illegal since the if statement is just dangling
}
```